# how to gzip response in embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gzip

how can I do this?
I read about compression, but not find anything about doing in embedded tomcat server. I read about Connecter class set the compression on in this website

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

but not in server. I have main method which starts tomcat server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you can do via XML can (most likely) be done with API calls through Java as well. In this case, if you can get a handle to the Connector object, you could probably set whatever values etc and enable compression.

Have you tried that? It would be something to the effect of

```
Tomcat server = new Tomcat()
Connector connector = server.getConnector()
```

Now set whatever values you want in your compression and after you are done, make sure to set the connector object back into the server

```
server.setConnector(connector)
```

I think that should be equivalent to the declarative way that's listed in the link you posted.